# Sorting second column relative to first column

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have got the following sequence (representing a tree):

**4 2**
1 4
3 4
5 4
2 7
0 7
**6 0**

Now, I am trying to sort this sequence, such that when a value appears on the left (column 1), it has already appeared on the right (column 2). More concretely, the result of the sorting algorithm should be:

1 4
3 4
5 4
**4 2**
2 7
**6 0**
0 7

Obviously, this works in O(n^2) with an algorithm iterating over each entry of column 1 and then look for corresponding entries in column two. But as n can be quite big (> 100000) in my scenario, I'm looking for a O(n log n) way to do it. Is this even possible?

Comment: Why doesn't the sorted sequence begin 1 4, 4 2, ...? 4 has already appeared on the right

Comment: If it's representing a tree, you could create the list without "sorting" at all. It looks to me that the end result is just a traversal of your tree from the top down.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Hm, I reckon I have to sort because I want to traverse the tree bottom up. That is why, I need the children (first three elements of sorted result) to come before the parent (fourth element of sorted result).

Comment: @Joni You are right, this could be a valid sorting. But In my scenario it would be important that all the children (1 4, 3 4 and 5 4) come before the parent (4 2) as they might need their children nodes to come before them. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: How does the list represent a tree? the children of (1-based) index k are 2k and 2k+1, or?

Comment: @bengro - I still don't get it. If you traverse your tree top down, you first get `7, 0`, next `0, 6`, next `7, 2` ... It's exactly the list you want as result in reverse *(and `parent, child` io `child, parent`)*.

Comment: are you able to use a hashmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assumption:**

I'm assuming this is also a valid sort sequence:

```
1 4
4 2
3 4
5 4
2 7
6 0
0 7
```

i.e. Once a value appears once on the right, it can appear on the left.

If this is not the case (i.e. all occurrences on the right has to be before any occurrence on the left), ignore the "remove all edges pointing to that element" part and only remove the intermediate element if it has no incoming edges left.

**Algorithm:**

Construct a graph where each element A points to another element B if the right element of A is equal to the left element of B. This can be done using a hash multi-map:

- Go through the elements, inserting each element `A` into the hash map as `A.left -> A`.
- Go through the elements again, connecting each element `B` with all elements appearing under `B.right`.

Perform a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the graph, giving you your result. I should be modified such that, instead of removing an edge pointing to an element, we remove all edges pointing to that element (i.e. if we already found an element containing some element on the right, we don't need to find another for that element to appear on the left).

Currently this is O(n<sup>2</sup>) running time, because there are too many edges - if we have:

```
(1,2),(1,2),...,(1,2),(2,3),(2,3),...,(2,3)
```

There are O(n<sup>2</sup>) edges.

This can be avoided by, instead of having elements point directly to each other, create an intermediate element. In the above case, 1/2 the elements will point to that element and that element will point to the other half. Then, when doing the topological sort, when we would've remove an edge to that element, we instead remove that element and all edges pointing from / to it.

Now there will be a maximum of O(n) edges, and, since topological sort can be done in linear time with respect to the elements and edges, the overall running time is O(n).

Note that it's not always possible to get a result: `(1,2), (2,1)`.

**Illustrations:**

For your example (pre-optimization), we'd have:

[image]

For my example above, we'd have:

[image]